# Delegate factory with SingleInstance based on parameter

Tags: c#, autofac

I have an interface and a class that I would like to create instances for:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Frob();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(string key)
    {
    }
}
```

The Foo class has a `string key` parameter that will not be known at runtime. I have created a delegate factory for this:

```
public delegate IFoo FooFactory(string key);
```

I would like to register `Foo` so that it has SingleInstance scope, but I would like it to be SingleInstance based on the key parameter.

```
var foo1 = fooFactory("abc");  // new instance
var foo2 = fooFactory("abc");  // same instance as foo2
var foo3 = fooFactory("def");  // new instance
var foo4 = fooFactory("def");  // same instance as foo4
```

Can I do this with Autofac?

Comment: The core of your problem is that you inject runtime data in the application component `Foo`. This is [not a good idea](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: @Steven explain how you would refactor it then? This is obviously a mocked up example but this class cannot be constructed without this value, and it is not known until runtime. I see no issues with a factory being used this way.

Comment: Have you read the linked article? The article discusses two solutions. Either you pass in the runtime value through the classes public API, or you inject a 'contextual component' that allows retrieving the value at runtime.

Comment: @Steven nope I didn't realize you put a link in your comment :) Checking now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a factory class that will create the instance based on a parameter.

```
public class FooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    public delegate IFoo FooBuilder(String key);

    public FooFactory(FooBuilder fooBuilder)
    {
        this._fooBuilder = fooBuilder;
        this._foos = new ConcurrentDictionary<String, IFoo>();
    }

    private readonly FooBuilder _fooBuilder;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<String, IFoo> _foos;

    public IFoo Get(String key)
    {
        IFoo foo = this._foos.GetOrAdd(key, k => this._fooBuilder(k));
        return foo;
    }
}
```

and register it like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
       .As<IFoo>();
builder.RegisterType<FooFactory>()
       .As<IFooFactory>()
       .SingleInstance();
builder.Register<Func<String, IFoo>>(c => c.Resolve<IFooFactory>().Get)
       .As<Func<String, IFoo>>();
```

Then to resolve get a `IFoo` you can rely on `Func<String, IFoo>`

```
c.Resolve<Func<String, IFoo>>()("a");
```

Comment: In your example I don't see how the public delegate FooBuilder is being used.

I'm struggling with a similar scenario - need to generate a new instance based on string parameter.